# Let us build a common utility class for asp.net together

Tags: asp.net, class

Which method would you like to place in tyour common class in asp.net application? A common function which you use in almost all your asp.net project question.

Comment: I like that all the utility function proposed to far are already included in VB: `myString.HasValue` is `myString <> ""` in VB (yes, really, it works "correctly" with null), and an `IsNumeric` function is built-in as well.

Answer (score 3):

These should have *always* been there IMO:

```
/// <summary>
/// Answers true if this String is not null or empty
/// </summary>
public static bool HasValue(this string s)
{
  return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}

/// <summary>
/// Answers true if this String is either null or empty.
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s)
{
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}
```

Because going *back* to type `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` instead of continuing on feels so damn unnatural, at least to me anyway.  Love it or hate it, *to me* (and I'm the one using it...) it's clear to read and saves me a ton of time, keystrokes and frustration.

*Yes, this will probably be closed soon, but, well, I felt like semi-ranting against lack of basic string functions :)*

Comment: +1. These are always in my StringExtensions static class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool TryFindControl<T>(this Control control, string id, out T foundControl) where T : class
{
   return (foundControl = control.FindControl(id) as T) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start first, This is the function I use in almost all my asp.net projects
**Function: To check whether string is numeric or not**

```
 public bool IsNumeric(string str)
{
    if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
        return false;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] bytestr = ascii.GetBytes(str);
    foreach (byte c in bytestr)
    {
        if (c < 48 || c > 57)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `IsNumeric("1.23")` returns false? good design?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(...)) { }` works fine. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Having a "common" class for functionality is generally not good design. Methods should belong to a class which encapsulates specific functionality.

However, one exception would be static classes containing extension methods, and I generally have this sort of pattern

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions{} // all extensions for IEnumerable<T>
public static class StringExtensions{} // all extensions for String.
```

Answer (score 0):

A long time back I got this function somewhere from internet and I still use it, not always to generate random password ;-)

```
 public static string GeneratePassword(int passwordLength)
    {

        int iZero = 0, iNine = 0, iA = 0, iZ = 0, iCount = 0, iRandNum = 0;
        string sRandomString = string.Empty;

        //' we'll need random characters, so a Random object 
        //' should probably be created...
        Random rRandom = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        //' convert characters into their integer equivalents (their ASCII values)
        iZero = Convert.ToInt32("0");
        iNine = Convert.ToInt32("9");
        iA = Convert.ToInt32('A');
        iZ = Convert.ToInt32('Z');

        //' initialize our return string for use in the following loop
        sRandomString = string.Empty;


        //' now we loop as many times as is necessary to build the string 
        //' length we want
        while (iCount < passwordLength)
        {
            //' we fetch a random number between our high and low values
            iRandNum = rRandom.Next(iZero, iZ);

            // ' here's the cool part: we inspect the value of the random number, 
            // ' and if it matches one of the legal values that we've decided upon,  
            // ' we convert the number to a character and add it to our string
            if ((iRandNum >= iZero) && (iRandNum <= iNine) || (iRandNum >= iA) && (iRandNum <= iZ))
            {
                if (iRandNum >= iZero && iRandNum <= iNine)
                    sRandomString = sRandomString + iRandNum.ToString();
                else
                    sRandomString = sRandomString + Convert.ToChar(iRandNum);

                iCount = iCount + 1;
            }

        }
        //' finally, our random character string should be built, so we return it
        return sRandomString;


    }
```

Comment: However unlikely, this could end in an infinite loop. Better off putting the acceptable chars in an array, and picking a random index than continually looping over a random guess.